# DynamicsCRM 2013 - How to Show (Inherited) Owner of Queue Item

Tags: queue, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, items, objectid

I have created a view for my Queue Items. In this view I show leads, orders, emails and quotes (Entities). One of the columns in my view is Owner (Activity). This shows the information that I want, but only for Entities that are "Activity Entities" (i.e. Task, Email, Phone call, etc). Is there a way to show the inherited owner of the queue Item object?

So if I have a Quote, show the owner of the quote in that field, if I have an order, show the owner of the order in that field, etc etc.

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OOB attribute `Owner (Object)` shows the owner of respective Activities, but the `Quote` or `Order` is not an activity type like `Email`, `Task`, etc. So they are empty.

If you pull up the respective owner of each entity type in that view, the columns grows horizontally and the empty values will be shown for other entity types.

**Solution**: Create a custom owner field in `Queue Item` entity and track all the owner field changes in all the current owner of your possible queue item entities using a plugin. Add that custom owner field which stores the current owner of respective Parent entity (Order, Quote, Email, Task, etc) owner to your view.

Comment: This is the solution I came up with as well... Honestly I was just hoping there was a more elegant way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: @user3617339 I feel it, but the limitation is the entity type bucket to hold different type of entity like regarding lookup in activity is not available in any other entity. For that QueueItem should be an activity, but there is no way we can put activity (Email) in another activity (QueueItem) and Order/Quote is not an activity (though I like the idea of adding any entity in Queue its totally complex..)